# i keep geting eror "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' " in javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript

i have tried to *delete* ';' and retype **case** command but nothing happen and still just getting uncaught error. iam get this from tutorial please help iam so new for programming :) 
can somebody tell me why the eror still poppin?? 
heres the code

```
//SWITCH STATEMMENT
var job = 'teacher';
switch (job) {
    case 'teacher';
    case 'instructor';
        console.log(firstName + ' teachs kids how to code.');
        break;
    case 'driver';
        console.log(firstName + ' drives an uber in Bekasi.');
        break;
    case 'designer';
        console.log(firstName + ' design beautiiful website.');
        break;
    default;
        console.log(firstName + ' does something else');
}
```

[this is the code and the error on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDkNd.png)

Comment: Asking your preferred search provider for the solution (how does the `switch...case...` statement work) would have taken less time then asking this question... -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch -> `case ... :` instead of `case ... ;`

Comment: okay thank you for the reference andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `;` after your `case "something"` instead of `:`.

```
var job = 'teacher';
switch (job) {
    case 'teacher':
    case 'instructor':
        console.log(firstName + ' teachs kids how to code.');
        break;
    case 'driver':
        console.log(firstName + ' drives an uber in Bekasi.');
        break;
    case 'designer':
        console.log(firstName + ' design beautiiful website.');
        break;
    default:
        console.log(firstName + ' does something else');
}
```

Comment: so i have to use : in case and default ? and all command after switch or not?

Comment: @starmsnoter what do you mean by "and all command after switch"?

Comment: maybe in case i want to add another different command inside that switch. thanks  btw

Comment: @starmsnoter you should put `:` only after `case` and `default`. if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: iam sorry where is the check-mark button?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png